# Decodificar un timestamp customizado (desde 1990)

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con datos donde la fecha me viene codificada en un *timestamp* que empieza la cuenta desde el 1/1/1990 según dice la documentación. La pregunta sería **¿cómo decodifico este valor?**

Primero me he planteado si `datetime.fromtimestamp()` tenía algún paramétro para especificar desde donde empezar la cuenta, pero si esto es posible, yo no lo veo...

Segundo me he planteado aplicar un *offset*. Es decir, si nosotros aplicásemos `datetime.fromtimestamp(mi_fecha_desde_1900)` tendriamos una fecha más pequeña, por lo tanto si le sumamos el equivalente al 1/1/1990, entiendo que debería funcionar. Algo así,

```
mi_fecha_desde_1900 = 1049565540 # Fecha a decodificar. 2022-03-16 18:00 aprox
f1990 = dt.timestamp(dt(1990,1,1))
dt_object = dt.fromtimestamp(f1990+mi_fecha_desde_1900)
```

Pero si hago eso me sale el 05/04/2023 18:59 y realmente yo se que debería salir algo cercano a 2022-03-16 18:00.

Por lo tanto, el concepto del *offset* es incorrecto? Me equivoco en alguna tontería? Cómo se suele resolver algo así?

PD: No se si influye pero la fecha cuando se codifica a *timestamp* tiene este formato, `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

¡Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: No cuadran las cuentas. Tu número 1049565540 interpretado como un contador de segundos equivale aproximadamente a 33 años y cuarto. Basta hacer la cuenta de dividirlo entre (365.25*24*60*60). El usar 365.25 es para tener en cuenta (de forma aproximada) los años bisiestos. Por tanto si el origen de tiempos es 1990 como dices, 33 años y pico después sale el 2023. O sea que tu código te está dando la respuesta correcta y te equivocas en una de estas dos hipótesis: 1) La fecha debería salir un año menos, o 2) El origen de tiempos es 1990 (¿será 1989?)

Comment: Por si te sirve de algo, para que la fecha te salga la que esperas, el origen de tiempos debería ser el 12 de diciembre de 1988. Una fecha ciertamente extraña... Creo que por alguna parte tienes un reloj que no está en hora

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia! La documentación sería [esta](https://help.campbellsci.com/crbasic/cr300/#Instructions/secssince1990.htm?Highlight=since1990), miraré a ver si es que el *datalogger* tiene mal la hora...